# Comparing using Map Reduce(Cloudera Hadoop 0.20.2) two text files of size of almost 3GB

Tags: memory, hadoop, mapreduce, compare, overflow

I'm trying to do the following in hadoop map/reduce( written in java, linux kernel OS)

1. Text files 'rules-1' and 'rules-2' (total 3GB in size) contains some rules, each rule are separated by endline character, so the files can be read using readLine() function.
2. These files 'rules-1' and 'rules-2' needs to be imported as a whole from hdfs in every map function in my cluster i.e. these file are not splittable across different map function.
3. Input to the mapper's map function is a text file called 'record' (each line is terminated by endline character), so from the 'record' file we get the (key, value) pair. The file is splittable and can be given as input to different map function used in the whole map/reduce process.
4. What needs to be done is compare each value(i.e. lines from record file) with the rules inside 'rules-1' and 'rules-2'

Problem is, if I pull out each line of rules-1 and rules-2 files to a static arraylist only once, so that each mapper can share the same arraylint and try to compare elements in the arraylist with  the each input value from the record file, I get a memory overflow error, since 3GB cannot be stored at a time in the arraylist.

Alternatively, if I import only few lines from the rules-1 and rules-2 files at a time and compare them to each value, map/reduce is taking a lot time to finish its job.

Could you guys provide me any other alternative ideas how can this be done without the memory overflow error? Will it help if I put those file-1 and file-2 inside a hdfs supporting database or something? I'm going out of ideas actually.Would really appreciate if some of you guys could provide me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you need done.  What do you mean by "compare each value"?  What is the output of this comparison?  Are you simply trying to run a linux "diff" command on two files in Hadoop?  Do both files have the same number of lines?

Comment: By "compare each value" I mean compare each line in input file 'record' to each line of files 'rules-1' and 'rules-2'. Nope, the 'rules-1', 'rules-2' and 'record' files don't have same number of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iif you input files are small - you can load them into static variables and use rules as an input. 
If above is not a case I can suggest the following ways: 
a) To give rule-1 and rule-2 high replication factor close to the number of nodes you have. Then you can read from HDFS rule=1 and rule-2  for each record in the input relatively efficient - because it will be sequential read from the local datanode. 
b) If you can consider some hash function which, when applied to the rule and to the input string will predict without false negatives that they can match - then you can emit this hash  for rules, input record and resolve all possible matches in the reducer. It will be very similar to the way how a join is done using MR
c) I would consider some other optimization techniques like building search trees, or sorting since otherwise the problem looks computationally expensive and will took forever...

Comment: Your suggestions are really interesting, I'll surely give them a try, lets see what I can do. Thank you very much!.

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/cluster_setup.html) find **Real-World Cluster Configurations**
it will cover file size configuration

Answer (score 0):

You could use the param "mapred.child.java.opts" in conf/mapred-site.xml to increase the memory for your mappers. You might not be able to run as many map slots per server but with more servers in your cluster you could still parallelize your job.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that. Moreover, I have got 32bit machines

Answer (score 0):

Read the content text file from the MapReduce function and read the keyword text file from the mapper function (for reading your HDFS) and split using StringTokenizer value.toString reading from MapReduce and in your mapper function write HDFS read text file code it will read line-by-line so use two while loops here you compare. Whenever you want data send it to reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Split the 3gb text file into several text files and apply that all text files as usual `MapReduce` your previous program.

For splitting text file I written Java program and you decide how many lines you want write in each text file.